# JavaScript function location.search regex help

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a JavaScript function within an html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
 <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function redirect() {
                var queryString = location.search.replace(/^?commonHelpLocation=/, '');
                alert(queryString);
                window.location = queryString;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="redirect();"></body>
</html>
```

The url I am on is:
`http://somesuperlongstring.mydomain.com/somedirectory/index.html?commonHelpLocation=http://someothersuperlongstring.somedomain.com/help/index.html`

Thus, location.search returns: `http://someothersuperlongstring.somedomain.com/help/index.html`

But the function returns the same string as well, however, the regex should return only `?commonHelpLocation=http://someothersuperlongstring.somedomain.com/help/index.html`

Is there something wrong with my regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there something wrong with my regex?

Yes, `?` is a regular expression reserved character. You need to escape it for a literal `?`.

```
var queryString = location.search.replace(/^\?commonHelpLocation=/, '');
```

Answer (score 4):

`?` is a quantifier in regexps. You should escape it:

```
/^\?commonHelpLocation=/
```

To check if you are on a new page (and to stop reloading it) do the same regexp, only with the function of `test`:

```
if (/^\?commonHelpLocation=/.test(location.search)) { /* reload */ }
```

Comment: +1, for addressing the second part of the quesiton and being 23 seconds faster.

Comment: yeah - the document.location.replace() is also used in the browser to navigate elsewhere, which will cause a page reload instead of a regex replace.  To avoid this - assign the document.location property to a new variable and concatenate (+) an empty string to force a copy and not reference - then you can use replace() as regex and send the ensuing string to document.location.replace().  HTH.